# Create a FILESTREAM-Enabled Database?

Tags: sql-server

I need to use FILESTREAM data storage features in SQL Database ,
so I want to know that how to create this database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use FILESTREAM data storage features in database you must create FILESTREAM enabled database.
Must specify the CONTAINS FILESTREAM clause for at least one filegroup.

Here are the sample script to create FILESTREAM-Enabled Database :

```
    CREATE DATABASE AccountSystem
    ON
    PRIMARY ( NAME = accountsystem1,
        FILENAME = 'c:\data\accountsystemdat1.mdf'),
    FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM( NAME = accountsystem3,
        FILENAME = 'c:\data\filestream1')
    LOG ON  ( NAME = Archlog1,
        FILENAME = 'c:\data\accountsystemlog1.ldf')
    GO
```

Here this script Create Database name "AccountSystem".
This database contains three filegroups PRIMARY ,  accountsystem1 AND FileStreamGroup1.
PRIMARY  and accountsystem1 are regular file groups that cannot contain FILESTREAM data.
FileStreamGroup1 is the FILESTREAM filegroup.

For a FILESTREAM filegroup, FILENAME refers to a path. The path up to the last folder must exist, and the last folder must not exist. 
In this example, c:\data must exist. However, the filestream1 subfolder cannot exist when you execute the CREATE DATABASE statement.

After you run this script, a filestream.hdr file and an $FSLOG folder appears in the c:\Data\filestream1 folder. 
The filestream.hdr file is a header file for the FILESTREAM container.

Important
The filestream.hdr file is an important system file. It contains FILESTREAM header information. Do not remove or modify this file.

You can use the ALTER DATABASE statement to add a FILESTREAM filegroup for an exsiting database.