# To create Filestream enabled DB in Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlfilestream

The following query is my first query on File Stream concept.

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2  
RECONFIGURE
go
CREATE DATABASE Archive 
ON
PRIMARY ( NAME = Arch1,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archdat1.mdf'),
FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM( NAME = Arch3,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\filestream1')
LOG ON  ( NAME = Archlog1,
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archlog1.ldf')
GO
```

First of all I go-through the following links for self learning the File Stream.

[Configure Filestream Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-and-configure-filestream?view=sql-server-2017)

[Create DB Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/create-a-filestream-enabled-database?view=sql-server-2017)

[SO answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988552/create-a-filestream-enabled-database)

Using these links, yet I got general error as

> FILESTREAM feature is disabled.

Let me show the Query, Error and DB's property

[image: Let me show the Query, Error and Server's property]

What can I do next?

**Edit: 1**

I did following process with help of [Restart SQL Server services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-2017). Still, error remains.

> To start, stop, pause, resume, or restart an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine
>    Start SQL Server Configuration Manager, using the instructions above.
>
> If the User Account Control dialog box appears, click Yes.
>
> In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the left pane, click SQL Server Services.
>
> In the results pane, right-click SQL Server (MSSQLServer) or a named instance, and then click Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, or Restart.
>
> Click OK to close SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[image: SQL Server restart]

We can see the `Data Engine` in Quotes. whereas, the link contains `SQL Server services`. Am I did correctly?

Thanks,
TamilPugal.

Comment: Did you restart the SQL Server service after reconfiguring `filestream_access_level`?

Comment: @DanGuzman... Server Restart.... I shall get approval from L3 persons.. Let me try.. But, Thanks.

Comment: @DanGuzman.. question has been update. Kindly take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dan Guzman.
I got solution for my problem. That is on [Enable and Configure Filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-and-configure-filestream?view=sql-server-2017). Under this topic.

> Enabling FILESTREAM

But I have no idea about this query:

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
```

Thanks,
TamilPugal